# Express Jest problem running test with Sequelize

Tags: express, unit-testing, jestjs, sequelize.js

**Problem**

While trying to run some Jest testing on my Express application, I encounter this error:

> FAIL  models/**tests**/user.model.test.js
> ● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Sequelize is not a constructor

  2 | const path = require('path');
  3 |
> 4 | const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    |                   ^
  5 |     dialect: 'sqlite',
  6 |     storage: path.join(__dirname, 'database.sqlite'),
  7 |     logging: console.log // Output logs to the console

  at Object.<anonymous> (models/connection.js:4:19)     
  at Object.require (models/user.model.js:2:19)
  at Object.require (models/__tests__/user.model.test.js:3:64)
```

**Code**

This is the actual code for my Sequelize connection:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); // also tried const { Sequelize }
const path = require('path');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: path.join(__dirname, 'database.sqlite'),
    logging: console.log // Output logs to the console
});

sequelize.authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Database connection established successfully');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error connecting to the database: ', error);
    });

module.exports = sequelize;
```

Then this is the code for my actual tests im running on user.model.js:

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { User, createUser, findUserById, findUserByUsername } = 
require('../user.model.js');

jest.mock('sequelize', () => ({
    define: jest.fn(),
    sync: jest.fn(),
    findOne: jest.fn(),
    create: jest.fn(),
    query: jest.fn(),
}));

jest.mock('bcrypt', () => ({
    hash: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('User Model', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

test('Should define User model', () => {
    expect(sequelize.define).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(sequelize.define).toHaveBeenCalledWith('users', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
          },
          username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
          },
          password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
          },
    });
});

test('Should create user and hash password', async () => {
    bcrypt.hash.mockResolvedValue('hashedPassword');

    const username = 'testuser';
    const password = 'testpassword';

    const expectedUser = {
        id: 1,
        username,
        password: 'hashedPassword',
    };

    User.create.mockResolvedValue(expectedUser);

    const user = await createUser(username, password);

    expect(User.create).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(User.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        username,
        password: 'hashedPassword',
    });

    expect(user).toEqual(expectedUser);
    expect(bcrypt.hash).toHaveBeenCalledWith(password, 10);
});
```

});

Inside my user.model.js file that im running tests on, I import the connection module with `const sequelize = require('./connection.js');`. I only run into the problem when I try and run my test, if I start the server it will start no problem and I can interact with the database.

**What I've Tried**

I've asked chatGPT it said to make sure that I have the right dependencies, and to make sure I import sequelize properly in the connection module. I've tried multiple different ways of importing sequelize, but same issue. I know the right dependencies are installed because my other tests work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sequelize` is a class exported by `sequelize` module. So you need to mock the class like this: `jest.fn(() => instance)`.

After mocking, the `Sequelize` class will become `jest.fn(() => instance)`,

`new Sequelize(/**/)` will return the `instance`.

You should use [Mocking Partials](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials), which means we just want to mock the `Sequelize` class and keep using the original implementation of other things.

```
import Sequelize, { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

jest.mock('sequelize', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('sequelize'),
    default: jest.fn(() => ({
      define: jest.fn(),
      sync: jest.fn(),
      findOne: jest.fn(),
      create: jest.fn(),
      query: jest.fn(),
    })),
    __esModule: true,
  };
});

describe('76657256', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(Sequelize)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(DataTypes.INTEGER).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed the 'Not a constructor' error but now I'm getting issues when it comes to using DataTypes from the sequelize class. For instance when I use 'DataTypes.INTEGER' it says it can't read undefined properties. The error is in both my Test suite, and the user.model.js file. I'll try and reorganize my imports and maybe mocking it.